# Is there any reason to Filter POST actions?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I have a custom `[AuthenticationFilter]` which simply redirects users that are not authorized to access administrative content.

I apply the filter to

```
[AuthenticationFilter]
public ActionResult Index() {}
```

But, I also have

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {}
```

for handling file uploads.  Do I need the attribute here?

My gut instinct tells me no.  There's no way to POST a file to the page because `uploadButton` is blocked from loading by the first method.

The only other security concern I can imagine is a cross site AJAX post, but this shouldn't be possible or at least is highly unlikely because its an intranet site.

So, is there any reason to apply `[AuthenticationFilter]` to the file handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never count on your client-side control (disabling the upload button) from stopping something from hitting your server.  End users have *complete* control over what happens on the client. They can enable controls, remove or modify hidden fields, intercept browser requests, or bypass the browser completely and make their own requests (with any file they want).

Any place that you have the option to add security on the server you should do it. There is no type of request you can stop by simply using browser controls.

Comment: I can see what you mean if I were say, using Javascript to hide controls.  But, in this case I do not send the control to the client at all.  It is stopped server side.  So I'm not sure what you mean by "complete control".

Comment: The end user can create their own upload button. They can create their own form that mimics your exactly and posts to your service. They could use Curl to programmatically post directly to your site with a request that is indistinguishable from one sent from a browser. They have complete control over what leaves their machine and goes to your server.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it would still be possible for someone to send a POST using something like Fiddler.  The effort to secure the method is minimal, so I would say better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I'd turn the question around and ask if there are reasons not to apply the AuthenticationFilter to the method? As long as you know that there may be a risk for this method, why not apply the filter; unless you have performance issues with your AuthenticationFilter, go for it. In fact, if you know your whole controller is destined to be used by authorized users, apply the filter at the controller level!